# Error running Python 3.4 with PostgreSQL (psycopg2) and Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

So if I start Python 2.7's shell with `python`, and run `import psycopg2`, I don't receive any errors. However, if I try to run `import psycopg2` in Python 3.4's shell, I get: `ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'`. On the other hand, importing django works fine on both shells (after using pip3 to install it).

Secondly, if I run `python3 manage.py runserver`, I get an error (see below), whereas I don't if I use just `python`. I think this is because of the first problem I described but I'm not sure (sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm really new to Django - trying to get through the tutorial).

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 23, in < module >
import psycopg2 as Database
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback(most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in < module >
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module   
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level: ], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 40, in < module >
class Permission(models.Model):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, * * kwargs))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 297, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 166, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 242, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 108, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level: ], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 27, in < module >
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

What can I do to fix it?

Additionally, I'm super confused on this whole Python 2 vs 3 business with Django (sorry again if this is a really basic question). When you run `django-admin.py startproject theproject`, how do you specify which version of Python you want to use with Django? Is it as simple as just writing your code in Python 3 and running everything with `python3` as opposed to `python`?

Comment: Have you run `pip3 install psycopg2` already? Did it give any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have run pip3 install psycopg2.

By default, `django-admin.py` will run using Python 2. That doesn't matter, since all it's doing is creating the folder layout the project.

Once the project has been created, you can write Python 3 code, and run your site using `python3 manage.py runserver` to use Python 3.

Later on, you might want to investigate virtual environments. If you create your virtual environment to use Python 3

```
virtualenv v -p python3
```

Then you can run

```
./manage.py runserver
```

in your virtual environment, and it will use Python 3.

Comment: I'm running OS X (forgot to specify that), but yeah installing `psycopg2` with `pip3` did the trick, missed that. If I don't use virtualenv though, will running `django-admin.py` NOW mean that I'd be using Python 3? Or does it not matter in any case and I can use either 2 or 3?

Comment: Yes, running `python3 manage.py runserver` is enough. I've updated my answer, hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as I switched from using Python 3 from Python 2.7 using virtualenv on a Mac. Apparently, while trying to `pip install psycopg2` from Python 3 it was still using the wheel created during the install made using Python 2.7. So I had to rebuild the wheel using

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple python versions installed then the best solution to install the psycopg is to download the archive from

http://initd.org/psycopg/download/

and then install in by running (in my case, I wanted to install it for python 3.4)

python3.4 setup.py build

sudo python3.4 setup.py install

Now, check if it is installed by typing:

python3.4

> > > help()
> > >
> > > modules

It should display psycopg2 in the list of modules.